# Save and load TikZ graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Outsourcing TikZ code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79594/outsourcing-tikz-code)

Pardon the question, I'm an undergrad using TikZ and LaTeX to write-up my final term report.

Is there a way to write the code for a tikzpicture in one section of the document and import it somewhere else? My report is on Knight Tours, and so the graphs have many verticies/edges and thus my document is separated by long pieces of code just to draw the graphs. If possible, I'd like to have all the code for the graphs at the end of my document, and be able to import the figures using a few lines elsewhere in my document? Is this possible?

I'm also CS guy, so this is mostly just for code readability and modularity than anything. Thanks!

Comment: have you seen [outsourcing-tikz-code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79594/outsourcing-tikz-code/79595#79595)?

Comment: That I have not. I'm basically learning as I go. But this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!