# subimport issues: tikz/addplot

Tags: import

I am using subimport to include .tex chunks from different folders. Everything except my tikz figures seems to work fine.  Here is a minimum working example:

organization:

```
main.tex 
> Folder1 > chapter1.tex
          > data > turn_0.3.csv
```

my main.tex file:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\newlength\figurewidth

\usepackage{import}
\begin{document}

\subimport{folder1/}{chapter1}

\end{document}
```

chapter1.tex:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.8\columnwidth,
    height=0.5\columnwidth,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=120,
    grid=major,
    inner axis line style={->},
    xlabel={Time [s]},
    ylabel={Badnwidth Usage [B/s]},
    axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
    no markers,
    smooth,
]
\addplot[solid] table [x index = 0, y index =1, col sep=semicolon, green] {data/turn_0_3.csv};
\addlegendentry{0.3 rad/s}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Network usage in bytes per second for a single robot performing a 360  [$^\circ$] in-place rotation.}
\label{rot_bandwidth}
\end{figure}
```

the .csv is a 3 column seperated by ';'.

I get the following error:

```
 Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'data/turn_0_3.csv'. In case you intended to provide inline data: maybe TeX screwed up your end-of-lines? Try `row sep=crcr' and terminate your lines with `\\' (refer to the pgfplotstable manual for details).
```

I can fix this be adding

```
\makeatletter
   \def\relativepath{\import@path}
\makeatother
```

in the main.tex and appending \relativepath to the

```
\addplot[solid] table [x index = 0, y index =1, col sep=semicolon, green] {\relativepath data/turn_0_3.csv};
```

But I would like to have a solution that does not require modifying chapter1.tex file.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: One option is to tikz externalize [Script to automate externalizing TikZ graphics](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/script-to-automate-externalizing-tikz-graphics) or using `standalone`,`subfiles` [Outsourcing TikZ code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79594/15717)