# \addplot table with input filename relative

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I include plots using matlab2tikz to generate tikz-files. There was a nice feature added which enables external datasets. A file plot.tikz is generated with the following code (unnecessary code is skipped):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table[row sep=crcr]{plot-1.tsv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

plot-1.tsv is located in the same directory as plot.tikz and has the following content

```
0   1.10061021788087
0.1 1.54421189550395
```

In my latex directory I have my figures organized in /fig/chapterXX
I have a custom command with which I include my figures: `\includetikz{folder}{tikz-file}`, e.g. `\includetikz{fig/chapter3}{plot}` (this custom command includes the file plot.tikz with the `\input{}`-command)

My problem is now: Latex expects the file plot-1.tsv relative to its tex-file. If I want to get it to run, I need to manually change the `\addplot` in the file plot.tikz to `\addplot table[row sep=crcr]{fig/chapter3/plot-1.tsv};`. I have to do this in each tikz-file and I need to know in advance where I will put the tikz-file.

Is it possible to tell pgfplots that plot-1.tsv is relative to the file plot.tikz?

Comment: Because you're iteratively referring in the same fashion to the same kind of figure at the same location, I'd aim towards, say, `\newcommand{\myinsertplot}[1]{\addplot table[row sep=crcr] {fig/chapter3/#1.tsv};}`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, here I'm having the same problem as before, that I manually have to set the folder structure for the datasets of my plot. I like the feature that I have separate tikz-files for my plots and the new feature of matlab2tikz for external datasets is also appealing for me but If I always manually have to change the folder within the tikz-file, this won't help me.

Comment: Does it work when you include the .tikz file with `\subimport` from the import package, instead of `\input`? See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60227/12440

Comment: unfortunately, using `\import` or `\subimport` it is not working. I guess, it is because of pgf which loads the tsv-file within the tikz-file using the `\addplot`-command.

Comment: I almost got what I want using the syntax shown in this question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160882/subimport-issues-tikz-addplot
The only drawback is, that I manually have to change each \addplot-command like this: `\addplot table[row sep=crcr]{\relativepath plot-1.tsv};`

Comment: @bene, as an alternative to specifying the path relatively, how about using the `table/search path` option that was introduced in PGFPlots v1.13 and works similar to `\graphicspath`? (Have a look at <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35863/pgfplots-from-file-search-path-looking-for-graphicspath-equivalent> for more details.)