# Outsourcing Tikz and relative paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, input, tikzscale, currfile

### Summary:

How do I get `includegraphics` to be relative to the current file, when using tikzscale?

---

### Details

Similar to [pmav](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79764/19326) I like to have a `.tikz` file which contains only the `tikzpicture` environment. (Main reason beeing, that I am to lazy to wrap all my figures in a full preamble like the `standalone` class would mandate, and that this is what `tikzscale` needs as input).

Since I like to use my pictures in different documents my latex folder looks something like this:

```
pictures
-TEST.tex %contains documentclass and loads tikzpreamble,
          % modified by hand to input the tikz file currently under development
-tikzpreamble.tex
-picture1.tikz
-picture2.tikz
documentA
-documentA.tex
-...
documentB
...
```

While this flow works without fault for pure tikzpictures, I lately had a tikzpicture using `\includegraphics`. While it was no problem when I worked from inside the pictures folder  (TEST.tex), I soon hit the issue that the input path is relative to the main tex file, rather than the current file.

A quick google search led me to the [`import`](http://ctan.sciserv.eu/macros/latex/contrib/import/import.pdf) package with `subimport`. While this allows me to load the tikzpicture in a way that the `includegraphics` inside the `tikzpicture` works, it does not support `tikzscale`.

I thought I got lucky when I read the following in the [tikzscale documentation](ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzscale/tikzscale.pdf), in regard to the problem:

> If both tikzscale and currfile are loaded, the limitation is fixed, so
>   that both [includegraphics relative to main file AND relative to current file] \includegraphics commands succeed.

However, for me it does not work. I.e. the following results in the png not beeing found:

Filetree:

```
pictures/tikzpicture.tikz
pictures/OtherSources/png.png
document1/doc1.tex
```

doc1.tex:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\begin{document}
    \input{../pictures/tikzpicture.tikz}
\end{document}
```

tikzpicture.tikz

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\includegraphics{OtherSources/png.png}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

=> Error message:

> Package pdftex.def Error: File `OtherSources/png.png' not
>   found. ...ng.png}

Related: [Outsourcing TikZ code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79594/19326)

Comment: Have you tried setting `\graphicspath{}`? That might work. If it were me, I'd probably just use sym links.

Comment: @cfr: since I work from both Windows and Linux machines, I am reluctant about using symlinks. Even though modern versions of windows support them, [git does not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11662868/258418). (There is a comment from April this year, indicating it is still unsupported). As for the `graphicspath` I did not even know that it exists, so I will try that, however I would love the native feel of just amking all `input` and co commands relative to the current file.

Comment: If I used Windows, I'd be reluctant to do anything ;). I'm just used to doing it so thought I'd mention it. I suspect the directory structure shown in the package documentation's example is significant so that if you want to use the feature, you probably need a similar structure.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you don't need `tikzscale`, but if you need it in order to import tikz images with `\includegraphics` I see two solutions.

One is to patch the `\includegraphics` using `etoolbox` to make it compatible with `import` package. But I'm not competent enough to show you how to do this.

The other one is to use a personal macro `myinput` to specify the path, and then use this path in the subdocument. Here is your MWE :

doc1.tex:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{tikzscale} % not needed in this example
\newcommand{\myinput}[2]{%
  \edef\mypath{#1}
  \input{#1#2}
}
\begin{document}
    \myinput{../pictures/}{tikzpicture.tikz}
\end{document}
```

tikzpicture.tikz:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {\includegraphics{\mypath OtherSources/png.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Note:** I'm surprised that you include `png` inside `tikzpicture` directly. I modified this by including the image inside a node.