# Is there latex package/command to convert text to image? (Like rasterization in Photoshop)

Tags: convert, copyright

I want to produce some **observable but not selectable** text as a part of pdf files, such as a table.
It's feasible but not convenient to convert these content to standalone images, and use `\includegrapics` command.

So I wonder if their could be some packages/commands for such convert, may be:
`\converttoimage{blabla}`
or environment:

```
\begin{converttoimage}
    blabla
\end{converttoimage}
```

Comment: given the wide availability of ocr even ocr to latex markup, in practice making an image doesn't seriously inconvenience anyone who wants to copy the text.

Comment: @CK Are you sure that's a good idea? If someone really wants to copy your table, they will find a way. On the other hand, you are making your document harder to read for e.g. people who use screen readers or want to search in your document.

Comment: Related question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680499/externalizing-arbitrary-stuff

Comment: A related question with approaches to make the entire pdf non-copyable, which also contains interesting discussion on the problems with such an approach, is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11307/is-it-possible-to-produce-a-pdf-with-un-copyable-text and [the 34 questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/11307?lq=1) linked to that question.